# Timed event handlers in Android

Tags: android

I'm having an awful time trying to get a simple Android app to work properly.  I've very little experience in Java, having come from C, and I'm trying to start small with a simple clock app that will update the display every second.  Here's my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String currentdatetime = 
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    final TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String currentdatetime = 
                    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            textview.setText(currentdatetime);
        }
    };
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
    textview.setTextSize(20);
    textview.setText(currentdatetime);
    setContentView(textview);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    runnable.run();
}
```

I'm running this in Debian Linux with the Google-provided ADT bundle, and have followed all the suggestions Eclipse gives for fixing these problems, to no avail.  The program compiles fine and displays exactly as I'd expect it to, except that it does not update at all.  I've scoured Google as best I can and have followed many different ways of doing this, but I've not been successful.

What I'd expect this program to do is, on creation, set "currentdatetime" to the current date and time, stick it in a TextView, and then change the TextView to the main view.  I'd expect it to then hit `handler.postDelayed` and do this again every thousand milliseconds.  Clearly, though, that's not what's happening.

I'm afraid I'm completely lost.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Well, appears that I was on rather the wrong track.  I've got the code working now, rather more neatly, with the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String currentDateTimeString = 
                        DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    textview.setTextSize(60);
                    textview.setText(currentDateTimeString);
                    setContentView(textview);
                }
            });
        }
    },1000,1000);
}
```

So thanks to anyone who was getting ready to answer.

Comment: Well, it may appear to work, but it's not really the best way to do it.
You're setting the content view each second - it only needs to be set once.

Actually, there's really no reason to create the TextView in code at all.
Just include it in your layout xml file (activity_main.xml), and then use findViewById() to find it. Then you can set the TextView's text each second, without having do setContentView() repeatedly.